# SSL certificate vs JWT

Tags: rest, ssl, ssl-certificate, jwt

I am pretty to new to authentication and app security concepts.I am trying to build REST based api's which will be consumed by a mobile application . As part of the application security i am looking to secure our communication from client to server through SSL certificates. With that said do i need JWT on top of this? . I understand that JWT makes the client-server authentication seamless with token based approach. Is that something can we not achieve it through SSL certificate based mechanism?. Appreciate some insights into JWT vs SSL

Thank you

Comment: Properly configured SSL will authenticate the server to the client and create an encrypted connection between the authenticated server and the (unknown) client. If the server needs to authenticate the client then you will need something additional. I don't know about JWT but perhaps that's where it comes in.

Comment: @JamesKPolk no, TLS allows symmetric authentication, with a certificate on the client side the server could authenticate the client in the same way that the client authentifies the server. For example, it was done like that in first version of French customs website where each individual had a X509 certificate to prove its identity to the server before entering its account related to the money he needs to pay the country. JWT is defined in RFC7519: *JSON Web Token (JWT) is a compact, URL-safe means of representing
   claims to be transferred between two parties.*

Comment: @PatrickMevzek: The difficulty of managing client-side certificates makes SSL client authentication a non-starter for most applications. But it's true, I don't know anything about JWT.

Comment: @JamesKPolk It all depends of the setup (here it seems between one application and a server, so only one certificate on both side), and it is technically possible. Like the example I gave: **millions** of French individuals had at one point individual certificates to be authenticated when going to French website for government taxing.  It is completely orthogonal to JWT, it does not cater for the same goals, as one (TLS) encrypts the transport where the other (JWT) provides features at rest (the token itself is encrypted).

Comment: @PatrickMevzek i thought that JWT is encoded and not encypted

Comment: @Shift'NTab See RFC7519 and its section 12: "A JWT may contain privacy-sensitive information.  When this is the
   case, measures MUST be taken to prevent disclosure of this
   information to unintended parties.  One way to achieve this is to use
   an encrypted JWT and authenticate the recipient.  Another way is to
   ensure that JWTs containing unencrypted privacy-sensitive information
   are only transmitted using protocols utilizing encryption that
   support endpoint authentication, such as Transport Layer Security
   (TLS). ". It can use "JSON Web Encryption (JWE)", appendix A.1

Comment: It just a bit of confusion, JWT are encoded although it can be encrypted. According to their site, The claims in a JWT are encoded as a JSON object that is digitally signed using JSON Web Signature (JWS)

Comment: JWT is just a format. Nothing more, nothing less.
@Shift 'N Tab is wrong. A JWT can be signed (JWS -> see RFC7515) or encrypted (JWE -> see RFC7516) or both